# Directives for forms and $invalid property

Tags: angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive to be use inside a form. The idea is to wrap the functionality of errors and validations. The problem I have is that the directive is working, but the form $invalid is not set property.

Here is my code:

```
 this.fgAdmin.directive('fgTextField', [
  'uniqueNameGenerator', 'i18nService', function(uniqueNameGenerator, i18nService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        model: '=ngModel',
        form: '=',
        label: '@'
      },
      compile: function(element, attrs) {
        var $column, $error, $field, $label, $row, $wrapper, columns, formField, name;

        $wrapper = element;
        ------ here i create other html elements just for wrapping the element with Zurb foundation *
        name = uniqueNameGenerator();
        formField = "form['" + name + "']";
        $field = angular.element("<input type='text' id='" + name + "' name='" + name + "'/>");
        $field.attr('ng-model', 'model');
        $field.attr('ng-class', "{error: " + formField + ".$dirty && " + formField + ".$invalid}");
        if ('true' === attrs.required) {
          $field.attr('required', true);
        }
        $label = angular.element("<label>{{label}}</label>");
        $label.attr('ng-class', "{error: " + formField + ".$dirty && " + formField + ".$invalid}");
        $wrapper.append($label);
        $wrapper.append($field);
        ----
      },
      controller: [
        '$scope', function($scope) {
         ---
        }
      ]
    };
  }
]);
```

the html

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div fg-text-field
      ng-model="model.name"
      label="Nombre"
      form="form"
      required="true"/>
  </form>
  <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="button success right" ng-click="save()">{{t.save}}</button>
```

So, the idea is that the save button remains disabled till the user completes the required field.

When I input some text (the input has the required), the save button is still disabled even do the form models are valid. The form $invalid property is set to false, and should be true after the user input of the field.

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance